# how to give connection in web config file?

Tags: asp.net

since we give connection in aspx.cs file we want to give connection in web config file .how to give connection.

Comment: maybe you mean put the connection string in the webcongif?... a web config is a configuration file...

Comment: @pradeep, the way this site works is that when someone answers your question and it's the correct answer, then please mark it as the correct answer by clicking on the big tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean connection string?

If so then what I do is have my web.config file like this;

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

And then I have a connectionstrings.config file;

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Production" connectionString="Data Source=MYDS; Initial Catalog=InitCat; User ID=UID; Password='Password';"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PreProduction" connectionString="Data Source=MYDS; Initial Catalog=InitCat; User ID=UID; Password='Password';"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Development" connectionString="Data Source=MYDS; Initial Catalog=InitCat; User ID=UID; Password='Password';"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then, based on a flag, I load the relevant connection string using;

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PrePorduction"].ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ConnectionStrings element in the Configuration settings. If you want to know the specific format for different providers and various options that can be specified in the connection string property have a look at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connecctionstrings.com/)

Comment: I don't think this is what's being asked as the OP says they have the connection in the aspx.cs file.  Difficult to tell what is being asked though

Comment: aspx.cs file we give connection.but i don't want give connection in web aspx.cs file insted of that i want to give connection in web config file .so how to give the connection.